# How to Grab MAC Address of Active Ethernet Connection in Bash Script?

Tags: bash

Simple Question:

How do I grab the MAC address of the active Ethernet connection in a bash script?

I currently have:

```
set - `/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | head -1`
MAC=$5
```

Which outputs the MAC address of the eth0, but if it's eth1 that's active, I want that instead.

Could I beforehand execute `ifconfig | grep inet` but that wouldn't tell me which interface is active, just that one is active.  I need to grab the line above it to tell me which one is the active connection.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "active interface"? Up? Carrying traffic? Associated with a default route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
set - `ifconfig | grep -B 1 inet | head -1`
MAC=$5
```

I grep'd the `inet` string and returned the line before.  Then use head to grab the first line.

Comment: This will not give you the MAC of the "active interface"

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like this

```
ifconfig | awk '/eth/ { print $5 }'
```

also an option... depending on user may need to specify /sbin/ifconfig in the xargs

```
route | awk '/default/ { print $NF }' | xargs -I {} ifconfig {} | awk '/HWaddr/ { print $5 }'
```

Comment: This will list the MAC address of ALL eth interfaces, where as I only wanted to grab the MAC address of the active eth interface.

Comment: Did the second one do the desired action?